# border radius not working on IE, what library or css hack do I use

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, css

I want to style some forms on my app in IE8 but I always have a problem with css3.
I already tried with css3pie but I'm not very satisfied. I would be very happy if there is a jQuery plugin to do that. I wonder if it is possible to trick IE8 with Something like.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

If someone's solved this  please let me know.
Thank's.

Comment: "I already tried with css3pie but I'm not very satisfied" - what's wrong with it? And no, you can't tell IE8 to magically render as IE9 :)

Comment: The `X-UA-Compatible` trick only works for "downgrading" IE, or forcing it to run at its actual version, but not for "upgrading" beyond the actual version. You can't magically add IE9 features to IE8 if they aren't present already.

Comment: in modal windows I have a lot of problems because of this library, for example when I do scroll inside of modal window , the background of my buttons for which I have applied css3 and called pie.js library is moving up and down and many other. I concluded is better to use this library when you have a small website and not an heavy app in which you are using different frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
[Rounded Corners in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

At the bottom there are some links to different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

- Use some sort of javascript-based pseudo-compatibility library (such as css3pie). Since these libraries basically resort to hacks in a controlled way, your results are going to be somewhat correct, but not necessarily perfect.
- Use a different / additional stylesheet for IE8 (and earlier), adding rounded borders using old-school methods (images for the corners, with some wild floating and positioning tricks; or worse, abusing list item bullet points for rounded corners).
- Use old-school methods for *all* browsers - this will work, but you will miss out on smoothly-scaled vector corners (i.e., it will pixelate when the user zooms in).
- Make a design that looks good enough without the rounded borders and let IE8 degrade gracefully. (This is actually the canonical solution as envisioned by the designers of 
  HTML and CSS.)

*Some notes:*

- IE8 (and earlier) is not the only browser that doesn't implement border-radius; Opera Mini, a fairly popular mobile browser, hasn't implemented them yet, and both Desktop Opera and Opera Mobile didn't include them either until version 10.
- Hacks that work on IE8 may not work on IE6 and 7, so if you choose that path, be prepared to manage four different stylesheets instead of one.
- Many of the usual old-school rounded corner hacks are hard or impossible to implement in fluid layouts, because they rely on absolute positioning and knowledge of other elements' sizes.
- Javascript-based solutions obviously break if the user has Javascript disabled.
- Over time, people *will* move to newer IE versions. IE8 is the most prominent version right now, but that's not going to last forever.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks

Haven't used it for border-radius, but other css3.
You would have to use borderradiusalt.js and apply it like this:

```
$('#myElement').css('border-radius', '3px 3px 3px 3px');
```

You also have to put border-radius.htc in the web root(e.g. where index.html is located) or the page that uses the js.

Comment: This is not working on IE 8!!! I added on document ready that library call and is loading alert: `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.matrixContent').css('border-radius', '3px 3px 3px 3px');
   alert('alertXXX');`
});

Comment: You also have to put border-radius.htc in the web root or the page that uses the js file

Comment: yes I know, already added but this .htc files doesn't run on every server. On apache server is not running.

Comment: You can make it work by adding the correct mime type: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306231